# How can I send mail of complete form in php?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

i am having a problem in sending mail to my server. i dont know why the problem is occurring? everything is done perfect but it is not working maybe the fields are not filling properly and alert message is also not shown

```
if(isset($_POST['uname']) && isset($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['nic']) && isset($_POST['pecno'])&& isset($_POST['quality[25]'])&& isset($_POST['bday'])&& isset($_POST['quality[26]'])&& isset($_POST['postal'])&& isset($_POST['cell'])&& isset($_POST['houseno'])&& isset($_POST['mail'])&& isset($_POST['city'])&& isset($_POST['province'])&& isset($_POST['country']) )
{
    $_Name = $_POST['uname'];
    $_Fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $_NIC = $_POST['nic'];
    $_Pecno = $_POST['pecno'];
    $_Gender = $_POST['quality[25]'];
    $_Bday = $_POST['bday'];
    $_Qualification = $_POST['quality[26]'];
    $_Postal = $_POST['postal'];
    $_Cell = $_POST['cell'];
    $_Houseno = $_POST['houseno'];
    $_Email = $_POST['mail'];
    $_City = $_POST['city'];
    $_Province = $_POST['province'];
    $_Country = $_POST['country'];


    if(!empty($_Name) && !empty($_Fname) && !empty($_NIC) && !empty($_Pecno)&& !empty($_Gender)&& !empty($_Bday)&& !empty($_Qualification)&& !empty($_Postal)&& !empty($_Cell)&& !empty($_Houseno)&& !empty($_Email)&& !empty($_City)&& !empty($_Province)&& !empty($_Country))
    {
        $to = 'info@mymail.com';
        $subject = 'Join us mail';
        $body = 'Sender Name : '.$_Name."\n".'Sender Father Name : '.$_Fname."\n".'Sender NIC : '.$_NIC."\n".'Sender PEC Number : '.$_Pecno."\n".'Sender Gender : '.$_Gender."\n".'Sender Birthday : '.$_Bday."\n".'Sender Qualification : '.$_Qualification."\n".'Sender Postal Address : '.$_Postal."\n".'Sender Cell Number : '.$_Cell."\n".'Sender House Number : '.$_Houseno."\n".'Sender Email : '.$_Email."\n".'Sender City : '.$_City."\n".'Sender Province : '.$_Province."\n".'Sender Country : '.$_Country;
        $header = 'From : '.$_Email;

        if(@mail($to, $subject, $body, $header))
        {
             echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
    echo '</script>';

        }else
        {
            echo 'Please Try again in a few mints !';
        }
    }


}
```

html code

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">


     <input class="form-control" id="uname" name="uname" placeholder="Name" type="text" required> 

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Father Name" type="text" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="nic" name="nic" placeholder="CNIC/Passport Number" type="text" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="pecno" name="pecno" placeholder="PEC Number" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="designation" name="designation" placeholder="Designation" type="text" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="organization" name="organization" placeholder="Organization" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      Gender:  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" id="quality[25]" name="quality[25]" value="1" /> Male
            </label> 
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" id="quality[25]" name="quality[25]" value="2" /> Female
            </label> 
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" id="bday" name="bday" placeholder="Date of Birth" ><br>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      Qualification: <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" id="quality[26]" name="quality[26]" value="1" /> Bachelors In Engineering
            </label> 
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" id="quality[26]" name="quality[26]" value="2" /> Masters
            </label> 
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" id="quality[26]" name="quality[26]" value="3" /> PhD
            </label> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="postal" name="postal" placeholder="Postal Address" type="text" >
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control slideanim" id="cell" name="cell" placeholder="Cell Number" type="tel" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="houseno" name="houseno" placeholder="House Number" type="tel" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control slideanim" id="mail" name="mail" placeholder="Email Address" type="email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="city" name="city" placeholder="City" type="text" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="province" name="province" placeholder="Province/State" type="text" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="country" name="country" placeholder="Country" type="text" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  </div>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-default pull-right " type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: instead using mail() function of php why you are not trying to use SMTP. It is easy to integrate and you can debug errors easily.

Comment: I guess `$_POST['quality[25]']` is giving issues, instead of this try to take name as `quality_25`. Please do `print_r($_POST)` and check are getting values or not

Comment: mail() is working perfect in my contact us form in the same page but not working in this form i dont know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace @mail with mail

```
if(@mail($to, $subject, $body, $header))
```

enable error reporting

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Show last error with:

```
print_r(error_get_last());
```

and check php_error.log for a problem

```
phpinfo();
```

for checking if mail module is enabled in php.

If all pass, check `/var/log/mail` about the messages, here could be 1001 issues with network, server, firewall etc...

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that same code is working perfectly on other page so please check it by removing "@" from mail as adding this will hide all notices and it will display error as well. Also try to print mail body text before mail function.